# CountDownLatch Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a method getNewA() that is supposed to block until some other thread calls setA(x). Is it correct to use a CountDownLatch? I noticed that there is a data race in that there is a possibility that after gate.await() unblocks another thread will call setA(x) using the old latch, therefore it might be possible  to miss a value. I thought about synchronizing getNewA() but wouldn't that result in a deadlock? Any suggestions on how to approach this?

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class A {

    private int a;
    private CountDownLatch gate;

    public A(int a) {
        a = 1;
        gate = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    A getNewA() throws InterruptedException {  // wait for new a...
        gate.await();

        gate = new CountDownLatch(1);
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public synchronized void setA(int a) {      
        gate.countDown();
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: If another thread calls `setA` *before* `getNewA()`, what's that meant to do? Might a semaphore be more useful for you?

Comment: If setA is before getNewA(). A thread that calls getNewA() will return the instance without blocking

Comment: And if `setA()` is called twice before `getNewA()` is called, what happens then? Can two calls to `getNewA()` pass without blocking? If two threads are both waiting on `getNewA()` and a single `setA()` call comes in, should both be unblocked or just one? You really need to describe your situation carefully :)

Comment: Should `getNewA` really return A, not int?

Comment: The current code has a race condition: if two threads call `getNewA()` and block, then another thread wakes them up, then a fourth thread immediately calls `getNewA()`, it is possible that the fourth thread will see a value of `gate` that is set by the first thread to leave the gate, but which is then overwritten by the second thread to leave the gate before any `setA()`-calling thread has a chance to see it. That poor fourth thread will never be unblocked.

Comment: no getNewA() should not return an int i just made this example to keep it simple

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  You can reuse it just like you want here without having to create a new instance of the your barrier.

```
public class A {

    private int a
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);


    public A(int a) {
        a = 1;
    }


    A getNewA() throws InterruptedException {  // wait for new a...
        phaser.awaitAdvance(phaser.getPhase());
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized  int getA() {
        return percent;
    }

    public synchronized void setA(int a) {      
        this.a = a
        phaser.arrive();
    }
}
```

Each time  `setA` is called it will increment to a new phase and the `phaser.awaitAdvance(phaser.getPhase())` will return out.  At this point the new phase will equal the `phaser.getPhase()+1`

**Note:** this requires Java 7.

Comment: Any alternatives if im using java 6?

Comment: @xxtommoxx I thought of some usages with FutureTask but don't like it enough to post it.  I may be able to work it better.

Comment: @lhballoti Unfortunately not.  A SynchronousQueue requires the putting thread to wait until there is a pulling thread.  This requirement is for a thread to simply signal and continue working.  If there is no thread waiting for a signal then that's ok.

Comment: @JohnVint indeed, it didn't occur to me that the putting thread would block.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to handle synchronization yourself.  What I think you want is for the `getA` to return a value that is set after a thread currently enters.  You can use this as the `wait()` criteria.

```
public class A {

    private int a;
    private long updateCount = 0;

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public A getNewA() throws InterruptedException {  // wait for new a...
        synchronized(lock) {
           long currentCount = updateCount ;
           while (currentCount == updateCont) {//assumes never decrementing
              lock.wait();
           }
           return this;
        }
    }

    public int getA() {
        synchronized(lock) {
             return a;
        }
    }

    public void setA(int a) {      
        synchronized(lock) {
             this.a = a;
             updateCount++;
             lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Race condition is possible as TomAnderson mentioned. Thanks

Comment: The use of timestamps like that is vulnerable to race conditions if you get more than one update in the same millisecond - and a millisecond is a long time in computing. You would be better off using a counter than a timestamp.

Comment: It doesn't need to be atomic; all the accesses are protected by the synchronization on `lock`.

Comment: Think of it as an unusual kind of pair programming!

Comment: @Tudor Not necessarily.  As you mentioned in your answer, a semaphore will not notify all threads to awake.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Semahore`:

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class A {

    private int a
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);


    public A(int a) {
        a = 1;            
    }


    A getNewA() throws InterruptedException {  // wait for new a...
        semaphore.acquire();
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized int getA() {
        return percent;
    }

    public synchronized void setA(int a) {                  
        this.a = a;
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

If the semaphore has 0 permits left and two threads call `getA` one after the other, both will block and only of them will be non-deterministically chosen to wake up when `setA` is called.

If `setA` is called twice in a sequence, it will allow two threads to call `getA` next time, which may not be what you want, since both of them will get the same reference to `this`.